# Data structure for storing set of sets

Tags: ds.data-structures, set-theory

Let key space $K_n =$ { $1, 2,...,n$ }
Let Data Structure $D$ implementing a set $S$ of sets such that

1. All sets in $S$ are of same size $l$, $1 \le l \le n$
2. All sets in $S$ contain keys belonging to $K_n$ only

$D$ should support following queries:

1. $Delete(k):$ Deletes all sets in $S$ which contain key $k$.
2. $Insert(k):$ Inserts key $k$ in all sets of $S$.

An information about the nature of sequence of queries to $D$ is given:
Let $f(k)$ be a query sequence $Delete(k) \rightarrow Insert(k)$
The environment in which $D$ is to be used will always produce a query sequence like:
 $f(x) \rightarrow f(y) \rightarrow f(z) \rightarrow ...$

$Illustration:$
$K_n =$ { $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ }
A sequence of queries is given below:
$S =$ { { $1, 2, 3$ }, { $1, 2, 4$ }, { $1, 4, 5$ }, { $1, 3, 6$ }, { $1, 5, 6$ } }
$Delete(3)$
$S =$ { { $1, 2, 4$ }, { $1, 4, 5$ }, { $1, 5, 6$ } }
$Insert(3)$
$S =$ { { $1, 2, 3, 4$ }, { $1, 3, 4, 5$ }, { $1, 3, 5, 6$ } }
$Delete(6)$
$S =$ { { $1, 2, 3, 4$ }, { $1, 3, 4, 5$ } }
$Insert(6)$
$S =$ { { $1, 2, 3, 4, 6$ }, { $1, 3, 4, 5, 6$ } }

$Question:$ Can such a data structure $D$ be designed with supports both of the above queries in less than $O(2^n)$ time and occupies space less than $O(|S|)$

Comment: How are the sets in $S$ given, initially?  (Seems hard to give them using space "less than $O(|S|)$".)

Comment: (i) Can please explain where this question arises (per the posting guidelines)?  (ii) As specified, *each query returns no information*, so a trivial implementation that simply does (and stores) nothing will, technically, support the given queries.